# Rationalizing the denominator having square roots and cube roots

Tags: rationalising-denominator

In middle-school mathematics, the teachers always tell you that if you have radicals on the denominator of a fraction, then it isn't fit to be a final answer - you have to *rationalize the denominator*, or get rid of all of the radicals in the denominator by moving them to numerator.

Rationalizing the denominator is usually very easy, and can be done quickly using its conjugate. For example, consider
$$\frac{1}{2+\sqrt 2}$$
This denominator can be easily rationalized by using its conjugate:
$$\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{(2+\sqrt 2)(2-\sqrt 2)}$$
$$\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{4-2}$$
$$\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{2}$$

However, I have stumbled upon a new class of denominator-rationalization problems that I can't figure out how to solve. I was thoroughly stumped when I tried to rationalize the denominator of this fraction:
$$\frac{1}{2+\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

Can anybody figure out how to rationalize this? Is it even possible?

Or, more interestingly, if anyone suspects that it is *not* possible, how might one prove something like this?

Comment: Rationalize away the square root first, then think at how to rationalize denominators like $\,a+ b \sqrt[3]{n}+c \sqrt[3]{n^2}\,$.

Comment: **Hint:** $ $ if $\,\alpha\,$ is a root of $\,c - x f(x)\,$ then $\,\alpha f(\alpha) = c\ $ So you need only find some polynomial having the denominator $\,\alpha\,$ as root. Wlog we can choose $\,c\neq 0\,$ over a field (or domain).

Comment: @BillDubuque Have *you* already found that there is a solution, or are you just proposing that as how you would begin to attack the problem?

Comment: @Nilknarf The method I described works for any denominator that is algebraic, i.e. a root of some polynomial with rational coefficients. Rationals, and roots of rationals are algebraic, and algebraics are closed under sums and products. So they include numbers of the type you exhibited.

Comment: @Nilknarf  In case it wasn't clear, here is how to apply what I wrote to rationalize the denominator: $$ 0\neq \alpha f(\alpha) = c\in\Bbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha} = \dfrac{\beta\, f(\alpha)}{\alpha\, f(\alpha)} = \dfrac{\beta\, f(\alpha)}{c}$$

Comment: From a somewhat more advanced point of view, the reason it's possible is that $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/6}] = \{ a + b \cdot 2^{1/6} + c \cdot 2^{1/3} + d \cdot 2^{1/2} + e \cdot 2^{2/3} + f \cdot 2^{5/6} : a, \ldots, f \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a field and $2 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is in this field, so its inverse can also be expressed in this way.  You probably won't have much luck trying to rationalize $\frac{1}{\pi - 1}$, though.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed $\,\alpha f(\alpha) = c\,\Rightarrow\, \alpha^{-1} = f(\alpha)/c\,$ in the notation in my above comment.

Comment: By writing out $(a + \cdots + f \cdot 2^{5/6}) (2 + 2^{1/3} + 2^{1/2})$, setting it equal to 1, and solving the resulting set of 6 linear equations in 6 unknowns (with the help of Maxima!) I got the inverse is $\frac{1}{46} (10 - 14 \cdot 2^{1/6} - 8 \cdot 2^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 2^{1/2} + 11 \cdot 2^{2/3}  + 3 \cdot 2^{5/6})$.

Comment: Multiply by all Galois conjugates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always possible.

You want to multiply top and bottom by $M$ to get that $denominator*M$ has not radical.

As you have figured out:  If the denominator is $a + b\sqrt{c}$ you mulitply by the conjugate to get $(a + b\sqrt{c})(a - b\sqrt{c}) = a^2 - b^2*c$.

This will also work with $(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)(\sqrt a - \sqrt b) = a - b$.

So it's the same idea for $a + \sqrt[k] b$.  The trick is to realize that $(a + \sqrt[k]b)(a^{k-1} - a^{k-2}\sqrt[k]b + a^{k-3}(\sqrt[k]b)^2-..... \pm a(\sqrt[k]b)^{k-2} \mp (\sqrt[k]b)^{k-1} = a^k \pm b$.

Example:  To deradicalize $5 + \sqrt[3]7$ multiply by $5^2 - 5*\sqrt[3]7 + (\sqrt[3]7)^2$ to get $(5 + \sqrt[3]7)(5^2 - 5*\sqrt[3]7 + (\sqrt[3]7)^2) = 5^3 + 5^2\sqrt[3]7 -5^2\sqrt[3]7 - 5*(\sqrt[3]7)^2 + 5*(\sqrt[3]7)^2 + (\sqrt[3]7)^3 = 125 + 7$.

So to deradicalize $(2 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2)$ just deradicalize it term by term.

First let's get rid of the $\sqrt[3]2$ term.  So we multiply top and bottom by $(2+\sqrt 2)^2 - (2 +\sqrt 2)*\sqrt[3]2 + (\sqrt[3]2)^2$ to get $(2 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2)*[(2+\sqrt 2)^2 - (2 +\sqrt 2)*\sqrt[3]2 + (\sqrt[3]2)^2] = (2 + \sqrt 2)^3 + 2= 8 + 12 \sqrt 2 + 12\sqrt 2 + 2\sqrt 2 + 2 = 10 + 26\sqrt 2$.  Then we multiply that by $10  - 26 \sqrt 2$ to get $(10 + 26\sqrt 2)(10 - 26\sqrt 2) = 100 - 2*26^2$.

So example:

\begin{align} &\frac 1 {2 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2} \\&= 
\frac {(2 + \sqrt 2)^2 - (2+\sqrt2)\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]2^2}{(2+\sqrt 2)^3 + 2}\\&=
\frac {(4 + 4\sqrt 2 + 2) -2\sqrt[3] 2 - \sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]2^2}{10 + 26\sqrt 2}\\&=
\frac {[(4 + 4\sqrt 2 + 2) -2\sqrt[3] 2 - \sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]2^2](10 - 26\sqrt{2})}{100 - 2*26^2} \end{align}

Okay... admittedly that is a bear... but it is doable.

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: `It's always possible` For certain values of "*always*" ;-) This won't work out of the box for $1 + 2 \sqrt[3]{2}+3 \sqrt[3]{4}$ for example.

Comment: Beautiful?  Ugly as sin, if you ask me.... but doable.

Comment: @dxiv $\dfrac{1}{89} \left(\sqrt[3]{4}+16 \sqrt[3]{2}-11\right)\quad$ the method of the minimal polynomial is fantastic... provided you have Mathematica to generate it :)

Comment: @Raffaele Right about the CAS, in general. However, the simple example from my previous comment can be worked out by hand fairly easily. Just expand $(1+2 \sqrt[3]2+ 3\sqrt[3]{4})(1+a \sqrt[3]2+ b \sqrt[3]{4})$ and solve for $a,b$ such that the coefficients of $\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}$ are both $0$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:  for a shortcut in this particular case, let $a = 2+\sqrt{2}$ then use that:

$$
\frac{1}{a+\sqrt[3]{2}} = \frac{a^2-a\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}}{a^3+2}
$$

The denominator now contains only integers and terms in $\sqrt{2}\,$ after expansion, which is the case you know how to rationalize.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very general procedure for this kind of a question.

You see, in essence, rationalization of a fraction is converting the denominator into a rational, right? But indeed, it's a deeper process : Suppose a fraction of the form $\frac 1b$ can be rationalized, say written in the form  $\frac cd$, where $d$ is rational.

Cross multiplying, we get $bc = d$, or that $b$ times something is a rational. This equates to the invertibility of the number $b$ in the field of real numbers, which is true all the time. So every fraction of this kind is indeed rationalizable. But the question then comes down to how to find this inverse.

One way of finding the inverse is finding the minimal polynomial with rational coefficients, which $b$ satisfies. I'll explain why.

Suppose $b$ satisfies the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i = 0$. Then, $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ib^i = 0$, so that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib^i = -a_0$, from where it follows that $b \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b^{i-1}\right) = a_0$.

Rewriting,
$$
\frac{1}{b} = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b^{i-1}\right)}{a_0}
$$

which is the rationalized form.

So all you need to do, is to find a polynomial which the given surd, in our case $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2 + 2$, satisfies.

The minimal such polynomial is $x^6 - 12 x^5 + 54 x^4 - 116 x^3 + 132 x^2 - 120 x + 92$, which I found online. There's a better answer above on how to actually find a polynomial, so I will avoid that part, but at least this shows that fractions with "algebraic" denominators  can be rationalized using the polynomial they satisfy.

Comment: This is precisely what I described in a comment to the question.

Comment: My remark was merely to help readers understand how the replies are related. Nothing was intended about "the answer standing"  (whatever that means).

Comment: I apologize. What I meant was that I did not want to delete my answer because it coincided with a comment. But I took your comment above in the wrong taste. Forgive me.

Comment: Lovely method, provided you have Mathematica to generate the minimal polynomial :)

Comment: Ah, but of course that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Fleablood gave a method for your particular example but you seem to suggest that you're looking for a general solution. In this case, a formula may be given by $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{a}+\sqrt[6]{b}+\sqrt[6]{c}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}-\sqrt[6]{ab}-\sqrt[6]{ac}-\sqrt[6]{bc}\right)\left(\left(3\sqrt[6]{abc}+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^{2}-3\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)\sqrt[6]{abc}\right)\left(\left(a+3b+3c\right)\sqrt{a}+\left(3a+b+3c\right)\sqrt{b}-\left(3a+3b+c\right)\sqrt{c}+21\sqrt{abc}\right)\left(2\left(a+3b+3c\right)\left(3a+b+3c\right)\sqrt{ab}+42\left(3a+3b+c\right)\sqrt{abc^{2}}-a\left(a+3b+3c\right)^{2}-b\left(3a+b+3c\right)^{2}+c\left(3a+3b+c\right)^{2}+441abc\right)}{4ab\left(21c\left(3a+3b+c\right)+\left(a+3b+3c\right)\left(3a+b+3c\right)\right)^{2}-\left(a\left(a+3b+3c\right)^{2}+b\left(3a+b+3c\right)^{2}-c\left(3a+3b+c\right)^{2}-441abc\right)^{2}}$$ Which can be used to rationalize any $3$ term denominator with a mix of square and cube roots. It's a beast, but it works.