The conjugate of any number to roots to rationalize the denominator
I was wondering if anyone could help me explore this concept and give me guidance, to rationalize the denominator of a fraction involving roots in tis denominator we take the conjugate of its denominator. I have seen that to rationalize a minimal root you just multiply by a form of $1$ where both the numerator and denominator are the monomial in the denominator itself and I have also seen that for a binomial involving  roots you take the conjugate of it (to get a difference of square binomial) that consist of altering the sign (either from positive to negative or from negative to positive ) of one of its terms. But I was wondering what if we had a trinomial or a polynomial with even more terms such as $4$ how would we know what's the conjugate then? is there a formula or any concept I can use to find the conjugate of any number of terms? Thanks. (I was asked an example  so here we go : rationalise the denominator of for example 1+x/(square root of (3x+6)-cube root of (4x^2)- square root of (2) + 4th root of (12x-4))) (maybe I added too many parenthesis). (Please help me get more experience points os I can enter in other thread conversations and explore about this topic)

this is my first post please leave my a positive feedback

It might help clarify the question if you gave an example of the kind of expression you want to rationalize.

The general strategy involves cancelling roots one at a time. Unfortunately this is a lengthy and computationally complex process which only rationalizes the denominator (not terribly useful). Check out this thread, which I believe is asking a similar question with examples:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379383/rationalizing-the-denominator-having-square-roots-and-cube-roots

sure for example 1+x/(square root of (3x+6)-cube root of (4x^2)- square root of (2) + 4th root of (12x-4))

And now it would greatly help if you wrote your math formulas using mathjax.

The only issue with giving an example is that I am actually trying to find a general formula for this kind of problem, usually I have seen on threads how to rationalise 1, 2 or 3 roots in the denominator (the thread I was recently linked to was very helpful in getting close to a solution that is always true) but was still wondering if we can derive a concept that applies to all number of roots

thanks I am new to the website so I didn't knew how to do that I will now try to rewrite the problem using that method)
